# Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated. Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm trying to add support for Android API level 33 but When I target Android API Level 33 and try to create build it show this error, It works fine if Build with Android API level 32 without doing any changes..
Admob Version: 7.4.0

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

```
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:exportReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE

> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
```

Comment: Sounds like a warning not an error though .. does it cause any actual issues?

Comment: Build Failed After that error..